# Ionic v1 http request data and iterate to show the results in the relevant view

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a controller in which I am trying to get the results from a url endpoint using $http provided by angular js v1.

Inside the controller I have the following code:

```
  var api_url = 'http://exampleUrl';
  $http.get(api_url).then(function (response) {
    if (response.data.length > 0) {          
      $scope.data.result = response.data;         
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
 }
```

The result in the console is the following:

```
{"data":{"HTLS":  
[{"YEAR_BUILT":"",
"OPEN_TO":"",
"ROOMS":1,
"HTL_TYPE_NAME":"Hotel",
"HTL_CLASS_NAME":"2keys",
"ZIP":"",
"CTY_CDE":260,
"HTL_CLASS":"F",
"AVATAR_DESC":"",
"CNT_CODE":1,
"HTML_DATA":254,
"COUNTRY":"Country",
"EMAIL":"",
"OPEN_FROM":"",
"LATITUDE":1,
"YEAR_RENOVATED":"",
"LONGITUDE":1,
"HTL_TYPE":"HTL",
"NAME":"0Fenaki",
"ADDR":"",
"HTL_CODE":"1",
"TEL":"",
"AVATAR_IMG":"Penguins.jpg",
"CNT_RG_CODE":1,
"REGION":"A region",
"HOTELDESCR":"hotel description",
"CITYNAME":"a city name",
"FAX":"",
"WEBSITE":""
}
```

The html template is:

```
<a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-click="goHotel()" ng-repeat="item in data.result">
  <img ng-src="{{item.AVATAR_IMG}}">
  <h2 class="positive">{{item.rooms}}</h2>
  .........etc
</a>
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: @Mistalis I just want to make the results to appear in the html template. not in the console.. :)

Comment: Try this `ng-repeat="item in data.result.HTLS"`

Comment: @Hadi That is what I suggested in [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43755267/4927984)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON object contains an object that has the `HTLS` property (which is probably the array you are trying to iterate):

```
{  "data": { 
     "HTLS": [ { ... }, { ... } ]
   }
}
```

You should change a bit your `ng-repeat`:

```
<a ng-click="goHotel()" ng-repeat="item in data.result.HTLS">
  <img ng-src="{{item.AVATAR_IMG}}">
  <h2 class="positive">{{item.ROOMS}}</h2>
</a>
```